# Cotangent power series expansion about $z=\pi/2$ - would appreciate hints on how to obtain the result

Tags: derivatives, power-series, taylor-expansion

I know and have seen the proofs of:

$$\begin{align}\cot z&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}2^{2n}B_{2n}z^{2n-1}\\\pi\cot\pi z&=\frac{1}{z}+2z\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{z^2-n^2}\end{align}$$

But I am interested in the following series from Wolfram Math World:

$$\cot z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}2^{2n}\color{red}{(2^{2n}-1)}B_{2n}\left(z-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n-1}$$

I am interested in this because knowledge of this series would provide me with a proof, that I can say I came up with myself, that:

$$\zeta(2n)=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(2\pi)^{2n}}{2(2n)!}B_{2n}$$

My method relies on evaluating $D^{2n-1}\cot(z)\big|_{z=\pi/2}$ which I cannot do in any nice way other than use the power series I found above.

My thoughts:

$$2^{2n}-1=\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}2^k$$

So:

$$\left(z-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n-1}(2^{2n-1}-1)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}2^k\times\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\binom{2n-1}{k}(-1)^{k-1}z^{k}\frac{\pi^{2n-1-k}}{2^{2n-1-k}}$$

But this doesn't seem to be helpful. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

$$\cot(z-\pi/2)=-\cot(\pi/2-z)=-\tan(z)$$

$$\cot(z)-\tan(z)=\frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}-\frac{\sin(z)}{\cos(z)}=2\cdot\frac{\cos^2(z)-\sin^2(z)}{2\sin(z)\cos(z)}=2\cot(2z)$$

So we find:

$$\cot(z)=2\cot(2z)+\tan(z)=2\cot(2z)-\cot(z-\pi/2)$$

Which immediately gives the series of interest.